# Split and get second row as value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I'm using below query to split the names as shown below:

```
select value from STRING_SPLIT('Name1~Name2~Name3' , '~' );
```

How to get second name i.e, `Name2`, **without using `WHERE` condition**?

**Note: Names can be dynamic**

[image]

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Not duplicate, need to achieve it without WHERE condition.

Comment: You need the 2nd value respecting the same order from the string before the split?

Comment: @EzLo Yes, exactly.

Comment: Regrettfully `STRING_SPLIT()` does not return the position / index. There is no safe way to  get an element by the position with `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: There is a way: SELECT value FROM (SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) idx FROM STRING_SPLIT('Name1~Name2~Name3', '~') ) t WHERE idx=2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `STRING_SPLIT` you can convert your string to XML and then use `.value` to retrieve the 2nd element:

```
SELECT CAST('<t>' + REPLACE('Name1~Name2~Name3' , '~','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML).value('/t[2]','varchar(50)')
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Parsename has some caveats allowing for wrong values seeping in. I didn't debug why this happened, but it was enough for me to conclude the fallacy. This, however, is perfect.

Answer (score 15):

Try [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```
SELECT PARSENAME( REPLACE('Name1~Name2~Name3','~','.'),2)
```

output

```
Name2
```

> **PARSENAME** Returns the specified part of an object name. The parts of an object that can be retrieved are the object name, owner name,
>   database name, and server name.

Comment: when i'm using with 3, its showing `Name1`

Comment: @SantoshJadi actually it will accept only 4 values servername.databasename.shemaname.tablename so read about parsename you will come to know about this function based on value  we should write the number

Comment: Is there any way to dot(.) in to special character in context?

Comment: This will work only for maximum 4  blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T.* FROM 
(SELECT TOP 2 * FROM STRING_SPLIT('Name1~Name2~Name3' , '~' ) ORDER BY value ASC) AS T
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Comment: this can change order of items

Comment: @Rafal Yes, So that we can pick first record.

Comment: as stated in question you need to select second row and values are not necessarily in order in that string. So you answer will not work work all cases

Comment: Oh yes, I saw that comment now. I posted this answer before that comment. @Rafal